# Save files locally in objective C / ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, writetofile

In the app I'm currently developing i have run into a problem. I have several .plist files that store information. When the app starts it checks one of the plist files (that is empty from the beginning) if it is empty, and if it is it will go to a "user login view". After the login the content of the plist file will be replaced by the username. The reason i did this is because i don't want the user to have to login every time that they start the app. But this doesn't work for me, because every time i restart the app (both on my iphone and xcode simulator) all plist files have been reseted.

Right now I'm using the function:

```
[fileArray writeToFile:currentUserPath atomically:YES];
```

But is there any other way to maybe write to a file and letting it stay that way (until i change it), or is it maybe a specific folder i have to put it in to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to write to the app's bundle? You can't do that. It's read-only.

Comment: You're calling this method wrong. It _returns a Bool_. You must capture that result _and examine it_. That is how you learn that your write has failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mikle94 said you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

Here is the equivalent `objective-c` code

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:@"someUserName" forKey:@"userLogin"];
```

Then retrieve this info by

```
NSString *userName = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userLogin"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) instead.

Example:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject("someUserName", forKey: "userLogin")
```

Then you can retrieve this info by this line of code:

```
userDefaults.objectForKey("userLogin") as! String
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should also be in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I remember once having my file reset each time I ran the app. It turned out to be some simple mistake I was making.

You could do something like this if you don't want to use NSUserDefaults:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSFileManager   *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString        *filePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingString:@"/repository"];
NSArray         *fileArray = …  // Your data
NSError         *error = nil;
NSData          *fileData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:fileArray format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == NO)
    {
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:fileData attributes:nil]
    }
else
    {
    [fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    }
}

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```